# php js - Store user settings on his computer

Tags: javascript, php, settings, local, store

I would like to create a tiny script for web visitors :

A single sentence saying "Welcome {your name}." By cliking on {your name} the user would be able to write ... his name. I can do that by myself.

My question is :
What is the best way for the user to see his name the next time he comes back ?

How to store this data in local user storage ?

Thanks for your advice !

Comment: I believe you've answered the question yourself. One option is to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Indeed, localStorage seems very interesting ! Do you recommend me to use it instead of cookies ? which of these two methods is the cleanest ?

Comment: Cookies are not recommended when you intend to store large amount of information (for that use `localStorage`), though in this case it is perfectly viable to store just the name of the user int a cookie.

Comment: Thank you for your help, as a student, i will try both !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the name in the local storage of the user web browser you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (just simple JavaScript). Something like this:

**html**

```
<input id='name'>
<a onclick="saveName()">Save</a>
<a onclick="showName()">Show Name</a>
```

**js**

```
function saveName() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;

  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined" && name) {
    localStorage.setItem('userName', name);
  } else {
    alert('Sorry! No Web Storage support..');
  }
}

function showName() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    alert(localStorage.getItem('userName'));
  } else {
    alert('Sorry! No Web Storage support..');
  }
}
```

If you want the user to be able to access his/her info independently of the browser you should consider storing it in the database.

Comment: Thank you for your very complete answer, It just works perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

As you will save just a simple and non-sensible data, do it using cookies. It's easy and will make your job done.
[cookies() PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try both localStorage and cookies methods !